# MongoDB - Find only documents where their arrays contains the query's array

Tags: mongodb

How to get all documents with a find query where the queried array fields are exists in the document?

```
{
    name: 'test1',
    "array": [
        {
            "name": "100",
            "subArray": [
                "arr1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "200",
            "subArray": [
                "arr2",
                "arr3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If i use this query in the find({}) it gives back not only the good results:

```
$and: [
  {'array.name': '100'}, {'array.subArray': 'arr1'},
  {'array.name': '200'}, {'array.subArray': 'arr2'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator. Your query should look like this:

```
$and: [
  { array: { $elemMatch: { name: '100', subArray: 'arr1' } } },
  { array: { $elemMatch: { name: '200', subArray: 'arr1' } } }
]
```